# Sufficient conditions for determining if two algebraic functions are equal.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be, non piecewise, algebraic functions in $\mathbb{R}$ . If it is known that $f(x) = g(x) \forall x \in S$, where $S$ is some interval in $\mathbb{R}$ then is it correct to say $f(x) = g(x)$?

If so, how would one go about proving this? (I know its true if f and g are polynomials, but thats not quite the same as this).

If not, what would be an counterexample?

Thanks in advance,

-Almeida

Comment: Please define what you count as an algebraic function in this context, and what domain is implied in the question about $f(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: Domain is just some interval (a,b) over the reals such as, for example, (0,1). By algebraic, i mean this function is defined using only additon, subtraction, multiplication and exponentiation (where the exponent can be any real number).

Comment: If you allowed $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, that would be a counterexample (when compared with $x$).

Comment: $1-x^2 = \sqrt{(1-x)^2(1+x)^2}$ for $x \in S = [-1,1]$ but nowhere else in $\mathbb R \setminus S$.

Comment: @dxiv thats sneaky, nice find. Thanks a lot (again). As for varuns example, thats actually a very obvious one, my mistake for missing it.

Banning fraction exponents, is it still possible to fabricate a counterexample?

Comment: @Almeida If you exclude fractional exponents then the question becomes about rational functions. In that case the answer is affirmative, except you must add "*... $f(x)=g(x)$* ***on the common domain*** *where both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined*". For example $x+1 = \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ on $(a,b)$ $\implies x+1 = \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$.

Comment: Interesting. Where should i be looking (eg what websites/books) for a proof of this?

Comment: Nevermind that last question, it just follows from the fact rational functions are written as polynomials dividing other polynomials. Thanks a lot for the answers, and have a nice rest of your day

Comment: @Almeida Right. Suppose $f = f_1/f_2, g=g_1/g_2$, then $f=g \implies f_1g_2 - f_2g_1=0$ on some interval $\implies f_1g_2 - f_2g_1=0$ everywhere.